Connecting to SQL Server from externally with proxy server
I have a server running SQL Server 2022 with a couple of instances.
There is the need to grant access to an external supplier working with us on a project.
The idea is: the supplier connects to our sql server on a specific database they need to access.
We have created a configuration on a proxy server running nginx that allows the connection to the local sql server.
However, I cannot reach the database when testing from outside.
Is there any configuration I need to do on the SQL server to allow this hebavior?
Thanks in advance!
nginx entry
server {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/porgreencloud1433.log upstream_time;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/porgreencloud1433_error.log;
 
        listen 1433;
        server_name porgreencloud.company.com;
 
        location / {
                proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
                proxy_socket_keepalive on;
                proxy_pass http://dbtcp;
        }
 
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/porgreencloud.company.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/porgreencloud.company.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/sslsettings.conf;
}

SQL Server settings



Connection String
SQLUser = "ourUser"
SQLPassword = "LetsConnect2DB!!"
SQLServer = "porgreencloud.company.com,1433"
    DbConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & SQLUser & ";Password=" & SQLPassword & ";Initial Catalog=" & DBName & ";" & _
    "Data Source=" & SQLServer & ";Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & _
    "Use Encryption for Data = False;Tag with column collection when possible=False"


Please add the nginx entry, the internal port that SQL is listening on, and the connection string used to test.

@SeanGallardy hanks for your feedback. I have added the nginx entry and SQL server configuration on the original post. Please help to review and let me know your feedback. Thanks in advance, Regards

You're going to want something more like this for your nginx configuration. You may have to change the names to reflect proper dns entries and make sure various items are accessible from firewalls as well.
stream
{
 upstream SQLDB
 {
   server porgreencloud.company.com:1433;
 }

 server
 {
   listen 1433;
   proxy_pass SQLDB;
 }
}

